# Props received are undefined in react native navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

I am trying to access props passed to a react native component but it seems that props are not received by the component. 
The component which passes props(PastHires.js):

```
return (
  <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.heading}>Past Hires</Text>
      {
        this.state.boards.filter(item => item.driverId === this.props.user.id && item.hireStatus === 'completed' ).map((item, i) => (
          <ListItem
            style={styles.listItem}
            key={i}
            title={item.pickupDatetime + '  ' + item.hireType.toUpperCase() + '  ' + item.pickupLocation.toUpperCase()}
            leftIcon={{name: 'book', type: 'font-awesome'}}
            onPress={() => {
              this.props.navigation.navigate('PastHireDetails', {
                hireId: 12,
              });
            }}
          />
        ))
      }
  </ScrollView>
);
```

}

The component which receives props(PastHireDetails.js):

```
componentDidMount() {
const { navigation } = this.props;
// console.log(navigation.state)
const ref = Firebase.firestore().collection('hires').doc(JSON.parse(navigation.getParam('hireId')));
ref.get().then((doc) => {
  if (doc.exists) {
    this.setState({
      hire: doc.data(),
      key: doc.id,
      isLoading: false
    });
  } else {
    console.log("No such document!");
  }
});
```

}

This throws a syntax error: JSON Parse Error: Unexpected identifier "undefined"
When I console log navigation.state it returns that params are undefined

```
Object {
  "key": "PastHireDetails",
  "params": undefined,
  "routeName": "PastHireDetails",
}
```

Is there anything that I'm doing wrong here? Any fixes?

Comment: Check if PastHires.js can see PastHireDetails.js in you navigator, like
export default stackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        PastHires,
        PastHireDetails
    },

Comment: @mmelotti Should there be a stack navigator in pastHires.js? All my navigation screens are inside a stack navigator

Answer (score 0):

If you used react-navigation, try this for accessing navigation params

```
 componentDidMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    // console.log(navigation.state);
    const hireId = navigation.state.params.hireId;
    const ref = Firebase.firestore().collection('hires').doc(hireId);
    ref.get().then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        this.setState({
          hire: doc.data(),
          key: doc.id,
          isLoading: false
        });
      } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    }); 
 }
```

And refer this similar issue 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58279318/navigation-getparam-in-not-an-object/58280498#58280498](http://If%20you%20used%20react-navigation,%20try%20this%20for%20accessing%20navigation%20params%20navigation.state.params.hireId;%20And%20refer%20this%20similar%20issue%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58279318/navigation-getparam-in-not-an-object/58280498#58280498)

Answer (score 0):

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('PastHireDetails', {
                hireId: 12,
              })
```

In above line, you have set a navigation parameter called hireId which is an integer

```
const { navigation } = this.props

navigation.getParam('hireId')
```

navigation.getParam('hireId') will returns you an integer value

But in another script you convert that integer to JSON by 
`JSON.parse(navigation.getParam('hireId'))`

this will throw you an error

Try remove the JSON.parse as it is a integer already that you want